# Moving records around from tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, batch-file, logging, identity, foreign-key-relationship

I have a question regarding the design of two tables.

Table 1: The main table, called Batch. Values are added here from parsing files.

Table 2: This table works like a log table, every row that is deleted from table 1 goes here.

Example

Table 1

```
ID text
1  'bla1'
2  'bla2'
3  'bla3'
```

Delete row where id is 2 and 3

Table 2

```
ID  text
2   'bla2'
3   'bla3'
```

Problem:

What if I insert ID 2 and 3 again in table 1 and deletes it? Table 2 would have same data. How can I fix this? Should I just make ID also identity column? So when I add 2 records it would be this (additional question how do I keep counting if I delete the whole table 1?):

Table 1

```
ID
4  'Bla3'
5  'Bla4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a unique identifier for Table 1. This identifier should be unique to **this** table, not for the data you load. You can then load *id* 100 from your source file as many times as you want, they should get a unique identifier in the Table 1.

An Identity Column seems to fit your requirements for this. I'd look into more audit data as well, perhaps store what file it came from, when it was loaded, who loaded it, etc.

As for filling the log table, you can just attach a trigger on your Table 1 that fills Table 2 with deleted rows, should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Actually I have three tables, but the solution I want is that the ID ALWAYS increments, even if I delete the table, no counter resets. 

I am tryying to avoid this problem:

When I delete (trigger insert into table 2) ALL THE ROWS from table 1. And I fill the table again with values I got from parsing files.
I don't want the ID to start at 1, because when I delete it (trigger insert into table 2) I would have an error in table 2 (duplicate ID of int 1).

Comment: That's what the IDENTITY column is for. Just leave it alone and it'll just keep incrementing. Exclude it from your `INSERT` statements, leave it to SQL Server to fill it in.

Comment: silly me, yeah, I used truncate instead of delete. Thank you. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your design Table 1 uses a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). In this case you should define also a [natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) for your purpose. Then Table 2 will contains natural key and values of Table 1 erased data.

Because you can erase some data for several times, you should add a timestamp field you your table 2.

```
create table table1 (
   id int identity primary key,
   [text] varchar(50) not null unique,
   ... other data ...
)

create table table2 (
   [text] varchar(50) not null,
   erased datetime not null,
   ... other data ...
   constraint table2_pk 
      primary key ( [text], erased )
)
```

Comment: thank you for the datetime tip, I actually already have that one, but for clarity sake I omitted it.